# Cannot qualify with a type name because of scope

Tags: c#, scope

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public int num_segundos = 10;

    private void getHorarios( DateTime date )
    {
        List<DateTime> horarios = new List<DateTime>();
        for( var i = -this.num_segundos; i<= this.num_segundos; i++)
        {
            DateTime temp = date.AddSeconds(i);
            Console.WriteLine( temp.UtcNow );
            horarios.Add(temp);
        }
        foreach( DateTime a in horarios )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( a.UtcNow );
        }
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        getHorarios( DateTime.UtcNow );
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the error

> "cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with type name instead"

at that `a.UtcNow` instance. The problem is that i don't know a way to do that inside that local scope.

Does anyone here know how to solve that?

Comment: [`UtcNow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow) is static.

Comment: `UtcNow` is a static property of `DateTime`. Use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead. Edit: Actually, looks like you should be using the instance method `ToUniversalTime()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `ToUniversalTime()`? UtcNow will always be the current datetime.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

UtcNow is a static member, you can't use any instance to call it. To use it, you shall use DateTime.UtcNow.

BTW, I think what you gonna do is transfer temp format to UTC time zone. So use toUniversalTime() is a better solution.